# Adding custom font in silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, fonts

I tried to add google font to my silverlight project. so i downloaded the zip and added the fonts to Fonts folder:
[image]

I tried to load it like this:

```
<controls:DynamicTextBlock Grid.Column="2"
    Width="200"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize6}"
    FontFamily="/EZTrader;Component/Fonts/#RobotoLight"
    Foreground="White"
    Text="{Binding UserFullName}"
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding UserFullName}" />
```

and nothing happened.
what should i do to fix this?

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `FontFamily="Fonts/#RobotoLight"` ?

Comment: @ganchito55 it doesnt work ... i have just tried :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are using windows, Open the font you want to use with `Windows Font Viewer`

Check the `Font name:`. That name is what you will use when referencing it. **Note:** the font name may not always match the filename of the `.ttf` and can also include spaces.

You want to make sure that the `Build Action' of the included file in the project is set to **Resource** as you want to be able to reference it from xaml.

You can create a static resource for the FontFamily in your App.xaml so you can reference it throughout your project.

Assuming the name of the assembly for your project is `EzTrader.dll`

```
<FontFamily x:Key="RobotoLightFontFamily">/EzTrader;component/Fonts/RobotoLight.ttf#[Font name here]</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="RobotoThinFontFamily">/EzTrader;component/Fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf#[Font name here]</FontFamily>
<!-- other font resources -->
```

Then build the project.

From there you should be able to reference it like so

```
<controls:DynamicTextBlock Grid.Column="2"
    Width="200"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    FontSize="{StaticResource FontSize6}"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource RobotoLightFontFamily}"
    Foreground="White"
    Text="{Binding UserFullName}"
    ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding UserFullName}" />
```

Reference:

[How to use your own fonts within Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145196/How-to-use-your-own-fonts-within-Silverlight)

[Using Custom Fonts in Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29791/Using-Custom-Fonts-in-Silverlight)

[Using built-in, embedded and streamed fonts in Silverlight](https://www.visiblox.com/blog/posts/2010/03/1/using-built-in,-embedded-and-streamed-fonts-in-silverlight)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, check what the display name of the font is, instead of the file name for the part after the #. It may actually be Roboto Light.

```
<controls:DynamicTextBlock FontFamily="/EZTrader;component/Fonts/RobotoLight.ttf#Roboto Light" />
```

You may also need to change the build properties on your font file as seen here: http://geekswithblogs.net/mamta_m/archive/2010/07/01/adding-custom-fonts-to-your-silverlight-application.aspx.